# What is the ideal way to send a date parameter over a GET request in Play Framework?

Tags: java, javascript, datetime, playframework, get

I am new to Play Framework. I am able to send simple data types like string, integer etc directly via the request and access them in the Back end Java method.

When I try doing this in the route file,

```
GET    /food/fetchMealInfo/:noOfDays/:dateSelected     controllers.trackandplan.FoodController.fetchMealInfo(noOfDays : Integer, dateSelected : Date)
```

I am getting an error saying

```
Compilation error
not found: type Date
```

What is the correct, safe and clean way to transfer a date object from a front end AngularJS application to the Java application in Play Framework.
Please guide.

Comment: I am not experienced with Play Framework, but try to use `long` date representation. Use date as a long number, and convert it to `Date` type when necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a couple options. The slightly easier way to understand is to simply transmit the date/time as a `Long` (unix timestamp), and convert it to a `Date` in the controller method.

```
GET    /food/fetchMealInfo/:noOfDays/:dateSelected     controllers.trackandplan.FoodController.fetchMealInfo(noOfDays: Integer, dateSelected: Long)

public static Result fetchMealInfo(Integer noOfDays, Long dateSelected) {
    Date date = new Date(dateSelected.longValue());
    ...
}
```

---

The more sophisticated way would be to use a `PathBindable`, which would allow you to use `Date` within the routes file itself. However, you would still need to transmit the `Date` as a `Long` (the `PathBindable` would make the conversion if possible). Unfortunately, since we obviously don't have control over `Date`, we have to implement `PathBindable` in Scala, and not Java (Java would require implementing an interface for `Date`, which we can't).

**app/libs/PathBinders.scala**

```
package com.example.libs

import java.util.Date
import play.api.mvc.PathBindable
import scala.util.Either

object PathBinders {

    implicit def bindableDate(implicit longBinder: PathBindable[Long]) = new PathBindable[Date] {

        override def bind(key: String, value: String): Either[String, Date] = {
            longBinder.bind(key, value).right.map(new Date(_))
        }

        override def unbind(key: String, date: Date): String = key + "=" + date.getTime().toString

    }

}
```

In order for the routes file to be able to pick this up, you'll need to add the following to your `build.sbt` file:

```
PlayKeys.routesImport += "com.example.libs.PathBinders._"

PlayKeys.routesImport += "java.util.Date"
```

Now you can use `Date` within your routes file (as `Long`), without the need to handle it specially for every method that uses it.

```
GET    /food/fetchMealInfo/:noOfDays/:dateSelected     controllers.trackandplan.FoodController.fetchMealInfo(noOfDays: Integer, dateSelected: Date)
```

*Note:* This might not compile straight away if you're using an older Play version. I tested it with Play 2.3.8 and sbt 0.13.5.

It is also possible to modify the `PathBindable` I made here to use an underlying `String` instead, and accept a specific date format.

```
package com.example.libs

import java.util.Date
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import play.api.mvc.PathBindable
import scala.util.{Either, Failure, Success, Try}

object PathBinders {

    implicit def bindableDate(implicit stringBinder: PathBindable[String]) = new PathBindable[Date] {

        val sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")

        override def bind(key: String, value: String): Either[String, Date] = {
            for {
                dateString <- stringBinder.bind(key, value).right
                date <- Try(sdf.parse(dateString)).toOption.toRight("Invalid date format.").right
            } yield date
        }

        override def unbind(key: String, date: Date): String = key + "=" + sdf.format(date)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Send it as `String` and parse it in your action to `Date` object.

```
public static Result readDate(String date) {
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    java.util.Date dateObj = null;
    try {
        dateObj = format.parse(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        debug(date + " is invalid date");
    }

    return (dateObj == null)
            ? badRequest("Invalid date format")
            : ok(dateObj.toString()
    );
}
```

More samples of Date parsing from string can be found in the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4216767/1066240)