# Binding Android Retrofit Multipart Data to Play Framework

Tags: android, scala, playframework, retrofit, multipartform-data

I have been trying to bind my android multiform data to the play framework form binding. But right now its seems to be complaining that the **Date format binding** failed. Any help would be really greatly appreciated!

The format I am currently sending over from the android app is "yyyy-MM-dd"

**Things if have tried:**

- Tried to set my own **date format** in the "application.conf" to
  **date.format=yyyy-MM-dd**
- Tried to set the the java.util.Date format manually.

  ```
  val format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
    format.format(new java.util.Date())
  ```

Here is Http data mapping i receive from Android retrofit. I did a println on the "request.body.dataParts"

```
Map(stock -> List(11), productname -> List(pleasework), price -> List(11.0), userid -> List(test), brand -> List(nike), condition -> List(New (with defects)), date -> List("2015-09-20"), category -> List(Shoe), ean -> List(e0ee9583-fb10-43c1-80f3-c1725251adfc), sold -> List(true))
```

**Error message Play Framework is complaining:**

```
Binding Failed
List(FormError(date,error.date,List()))
```

**Play Framework Controller Code:**

```
val format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
      format.format(new java.util.Date())
      val userForm = Form(
        mapping(
          "ean" -> text,
          "date" -> of(dateFormat),
          "sold" -> boolean,
          "productname" -> text,
          "userid" -> text,
          "price" -> of(doubleFormat),
          "stock" -> number,
          "brand" -> text,
          "category" -> text ,
          "condition" -> text
        )(Product.apply)(Product.unapply)
      )

    def multiuploaddata  = Action(parse.multipartFormData) {
       implicit request =>

     userForm.bindFromRequest()(request).fold (
            errFrm =>{
              println("Binding Failed")
              println(errFrm.errors)
            },
            userData => {
              println("Success bind: " + userData.ean)
            }
          )
    }
      Ok("Receive MultiImage is okay!")
  }
```

**Android Retrofit Interface Code:**

```
@Multipart
@POST("/multiuploaddata")
void updateProductImageData(@Part("ean") String ean,
                            @Part("date") Date date,
                            @Part("sold") boolean sold,
                            @Part("productname") String productname,
                            @Part("userid") String userid,
                            @Part("price") double price,
                            @Part("stock") int stock,
                            @Part("brand") String brand,
                            @Part("category") String category,
                            @Part("condition") String condition
,  @PartMap Map<String, TypedFile> Files, Callback<Photo> callback);
```

**Android Fragment onClickListener:**

```
mDoneButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.done_button);
    mDoneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
// Calling the retrofit Interface to send Data and Images over to server
 service.updateProductImageData(mProduct.getId().toString(),
                    mProduct.getDate(), mProduct.isSold(), mProduct.getProductName(),
                    mProduct.getUserId(), mProduct.getPrice(), mProduct.getStock(), mProduct.getBrand(), mProduct.getCategory()[0],
                    mProduct.getCondition()[0], files, new retrofit.Callback<Photo>() {
                @Override
                public void success(Photo photo, Response response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "SUCCESS UPLOAD MULTI IMAGE!!! " + response);
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: try this https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/291. this link has helped me to resolve my date issue. given link is just hint.

Comment: Thanks alot for the link! i will try out : )

Comment: Hi Haito, thanks for your advise. does it mean that the best way to send "date" data over from android to play framework is to use epoch? I did a search and found that there is 2 recommended method "epoch" and "pathbinder" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30078615/what-is-the-ideal-way-to-send-a-date-parameter-over-a-get-request-in-play-framew

Answer (score 0):

I end up following Haito suggestion to convert the dates into epoch long values and send it over to play framework.
so right now after retrieving the **Date** value from the play framework i will need to convert it back to a Date and do my own formatting.

```
val datetime = new Date(1442802362000L)
```

**Updated Play framework code:**

```
val userForm1 = Form(
mapping(
  "ean" -> text,
  "date" -> longNumber, <--- change to long instead of date
  "sold" -> boolean,
  "productname" -> text,
  "userid" -> text,
  "price" -> of(doubleFormat),
  "stock" -> number,
  "brand" -> text,
  "category" -> text ,
  "condition" -> text
)(Product1.apply)(Product1.unapply)
)
```

**Android Fragment code:**

```
service.updateProductImageData2(mProduct.getId().toString(),
                    // Convert the date value into long
                    mProduct.getDate().getTime(), mProduct.isSold(), mProduct.getProductName(),
                    mProduct.getUserId(), mProduct.getPrice(), mProduct.getStock(), mProduct.getBrand(), mProduct.getCategory()[0],
                    mProduct.getCondition()[0], files, new retrofit.Callback<Photo>() {
                        @Override
                        public void success(Photo photo, Response response) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "SUCCESS UPLOAD MULTI IMAGE!!! " + response);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

                        }
                    });
```

I actually did dig out the DateFormat and Parsing Function and try to modify it. But I guess i am still quite new to scala and couldn't get it to work.

One thing i did find it strange is that for the def dateParse(data: String) Function. If I pass in the value "2015-09-02" it will work. But if the value is taken from it's function parameter it will work. I did a println on the "data" parameter and it is the same "2015-09-02" but i just won't work.

```
// This will work
def dateParse(data: String) = {formatter.parseDateTime("2015-09-02").toDate}

// This will not work
def dateParse(data: String) = {formatter.parseDateTime(data).toDate}
```

**The code for the parsing and dateFormat function:**

```
private def parsing[T](parse: String => T, errMsg: String, errArgs: Seq[Any])(key: String, data: Map[String, String]): Either[Seq[FormError], T] = {
stringFormat.bind(key, data).right.flatMap { s =>
  println("The Data is: " + data("date"))
  scala.util.control.Exception.allCatch[T]
    .either(parse(s))
    .left.map(e => Seq(FormError(key, errMsg, errArgs)))
}
}

def dateFormat(pattern: String, timeZone: TimeZone = TimeZone.getDefault): Formatter[Date] = new Formatter[Date] {

val jodaTimeZone = org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(timeZone)
val formatter = org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern).withZone(jodaTimeZone)
def dateParse(data: String) = {formatter.parseDateTime(data).toDate}

override val format = Some(("format.date", Seq(pattern)))

def bind(key: String, data: Map[String, String]) = parsing(dateParse, "error.date", Nil)(key, data)

def unbind(key: String, value: Date) = Map(key -> formatter.print(new org.joda.time.DateTime(value).withZone(jodaTimeZone)))
}
```